# MySQL database design user rating

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am currently designing a database of eCommerce web application.

I need to add possibility to rate a user by another user with 5 stars rate-system (like by amazon for example). I think that i have to add one more table to my database (i.g. USER_RATING). But what kind of relationship to use with my USER table?

My `USER` table has following fields:

```
user_id INT <- PK
first_name VARCHAR(35)
last_name VARCHAR(35)
email VARCHAR(254)
```

Table `USER_RATING` looks like that:

```
value FLOAT
time TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: add user_id, and voting_user_id to your USER_RATING table. Relational structure suggests you would associate the two by a common id. the voting_user_id is just so you can log who voted so you don't double cast. That's just the beginning of a rating system. Wait till you have to deal with anti-gaming logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to record when one user has rated another to prevent duplication so I'd suggest something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE user_rating (
    rated_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rater_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value FLOAT,
    time TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (rated_user_id, rater_user_id));
```

And create a foreign key on `rater_user_id`.

Depending on your application and the number of ratings you are expecting it might also be worth denormalising the design a bit, and record the `current_rating` (i.e. overall) and `number_of_ratings` on the `USER` table.

Comment: Thanks! About current_rating I decided to send a request to database, to get it every time "fresh".